# caffe numpy.core.multiarray issue

Tags: python, import, ipython, caffe

I have successfully built caffe, installed all required packages for python.

When under IPython, import caffe, I would get an error regarding failed to load numpy.core.multiarray, however, I can manually type 'import numpy.core.multiarray', then I am able to 'import caffe' without any error.

What might be the issue here?